# Realm fails in deployed WPF/Windows10 app with realm-wrapper.dll not found error

Tags: wpf, windows-10, realm

I am considering using Realm for a WPF/Windows10 desktop application but have run into an error when deploying the app using ClickOnce.  It seems the deployed app is missing the realm-wrapper.dll file.  I am using the NUGET REALM package and the app works just fine when run under Visual Studio (19).  But fails to run when installed using the ClickOnce installer.

I checked and the .nuget folder has the realm-wrapper.dll file in the runtime folder but there is no such DLL in the deployed app.

Can anyone shed any light on why this DLL is not getting included in the deployment?  Is there any workaround I can use - like just copying the executable and DLL files to a subdirectory and running the app from there ?

EDIT:
It seems that if I do a normal build for Release then the realm-wrappers.dll is included in the release directory but in another subdirectory.  As a workaround I am just copying everything from this release directory and the app seems to work fine.